# You are the admissions counselor at a school for magic

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus

You are the admissions counselor at a school for magic. You are tasked with the job of sorting incoming students into one of various study-tracks provided at this prestigious institution. The way the study-track system works, is that each track is denoted by - well, I don't need to explain that part to you, do I? You work there after all! Provided is a list of student applicants that still need to be sorted, and I trust you will have no problem assigning them to their appropriate tracks, although I get the feeling that one of these students is perhaps not exactly a match for the school.

**Applicants To Be Sorted:**

Grimm Bishop

Georgia Cross

Chiron Dijkstra

Ed Fish

Catherine Jones-Kittis

Piasco "Crazy" Seacrouch

Hemiesous Waster

**Can you find out how the study-track system works and place each student in their correct track?**

HINT 1

> The school did not begin as a school for magic. The track system was created at the founding of the school when its focus was on one specific subject. This subject is no longer the school's main focus, but it remains as a part of the first year curriculum shown below:
> *FIRST YEAR CORE CURRICULUM:*
>  - Astronomy 
>  - Cartography 
>  - Marine Biology 
>  - Medieval Literature 
>  - Metallurgy

Comment: Hey, I'd like to ask for a hint:
rot13(qb gur anzrf unir nalguvat gb qb jvgu uneel cbggre punenpgref?)

Comment: @BryanC Nope! I will add a hint to the question, though!

Comment: @Dylan why do you need to employ a sorter? We have a _sorting hat_, after all!

Comment: This puzzle seems to lack a crucial piece of information that would allow solvers to relate all applicants sufficiently enough to build an answer. It looks fun, but as it stands currently, it's a bit *too* enigmatic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just wild guessing, but maybe each person fits into one of the subjects???
Anyways... here is my guess:

Piasco "Crazy" Seacrouch belongs because of marine biology.

Ed Fish does too, for the same reason.

Georgia cross may belong because of cartography, and Georgia is a country/state and also its flag is a cross.

Grimm Bishop may belong because of Medieval Literature, and Bishop was a thing back then.

Since Chiron is commonly associated with the constellation, Centaurus, Chiron Dijkstra may also belong.

And since waste is generated with the metallurgical cycle, Hemiesous Waster may belong.

So my guess for the person who doesn't belong is... Catherine Jones-Kittis.